# Puedo hacer un adapter con un activity?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-listview

Soy una programadora novata y estoy practicando crear pantallas y otras cosas, entre ellas una ListView. El caso es que creé 3 actividades, la segunda pantalla (Activity) está linkeada a una tercera que no dice nada y quería aprovechar esa para crear la clase Adapter ahí, pero el AS no me lo permite, porque es una clase diferente de AppCompatActivity. Preciso crear una clase diferente? Puedo linkear esa clase Adapter con la segunda activity?

Gracias!

> Esta sería la segunda pantalla

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private Button acepto, noacepto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    acepto= (Button) findViewById(R.id.bacepto);
    noacepto=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bnacepto);

    acepto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this, ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    noacepto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Debes aceptar las condiciones para avanzar", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //(MainActivity.this, "Los campos estan vacios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    }

}
```

> Que me lleva a esta, donde tengo un TextView en el XML (Adapter_a3) que dice "Lista de productos"[image: Pantalla donde pretendo poner una lista]

public class ThirdActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.Adapter_a3);
}
```

}

> Yo lo que quiero hacer es escribir el codigo del adapter en esta Activity, para poder linkearla al mismo layout Adapter_a3 (el a3 es de Activity 3, para no perderme)

public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

> Pero no me deja... no sé si me expliqué bien

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un `adapter` en la misma actividad o crear una clase nueva dependiendo de la complejidad de los datos a cargar. estas dos formas se implementan de forma diferente.

Si deseas  llenar tu `listview` en la misma clase :

```
ListView lista;
ArrayAdapter<String> listaAdapter; 

// Instancia del ListView.
lista = (ListView) root.findViewById(R.id.lista_1);

String[] lista_Nombres = { // creamos una cadena para llenar el adaptador
        "ejemplo_1",
        "ejemplo_2",
        "ejemplo_3",
        "ejemplo_4"

listaAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( // llenamos el adaptador con nuestro arreglo de String's
        getActivity(),
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
        lista_Nombres);

lista.setAdapter(listaAdapter); // finalmente vincular tu listview con el adaptador.
```

Destacar que este es un ejemplo básico de un `listivew`, si deseas personalizar este control es mejor usar una clase independiente a la actividad, se te hará mas simple ..

Si quieres aprender mas puedes revisar el siguiente [enlace](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/), contiene información completa.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta @brendayanelaconz y me alegro que te haya servido ...

Comment: La verdad es que no entendí mucho lo del código, sólo: "Puedes usar un adapter en la misma actividad o crear una clase nueva dependiendo de la complejidad de los datos a cargar"

Comment: Te explico cuando creas una clase independiente como en tu caso es cuando usas una gran cantidad de datos o un adaptador personalizado en cambio en la misma actividad es para cargar datos simples como solo una cadena de string o un dato @brendayanelaconzi